# cannot read files based on regular expressions spark

Tags: python, regex, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to load files with data from 2015 to 2020 in pyspark. 
I use regular expressions.

All regular expressions were checked  on a site online. However when I use them in pyspark it shows errors. It looks like hdfs doesnt like parenthesis. I tried different variants

```
# .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/20(1[5-9]|20).csv.gz")

# .load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/20(15|16|17|18|19|20).csv.gz")
```

How to write them correctly so that I can load data from files from 2015 to 2020?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with curly braces `{}` and keep all your values.

```
.load("hdfs:///data/ghcnd/daily/2020{15,16,17}.csv.gz")
```

**`Example:`**

Reading `2015,2016` files

```
spark.read.csv("/tmp/20{15,16}.csv").show()
#+----+
#| _c0|
#+----+
#|2015|
#|2016|
#+----+

$cat 2015.csv
2015
$cat 2016.csv
2016
```